# How can i listen Google Cloud Pub/Sub messages continuously in FastAPI app?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, fastapi

I'm using Google Scheduler to send message to the Pub/Sub topic. I want to listen those messages continuously. My code executes only once and it doesn't listen.

**main.py**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from typing import List

from core.config import get_db
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

app = FastAPI()

from concurrent.futures import TimeoutError
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path("project_id", "subscription_id")

def callback(message: pubsub_v1.subscriber.message.Message) -> None:
    print(f"Received {message}.")
    message.ack()

streaming_pull_future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)
print(f"Listening for messages on {subscription_path}..\n")

with subscriber:
    try:
        streaming_pull_future.result(timeout=5)
    except TimeoutError:
        streaming_pull_future.cancel()  # Trigger the shutdown.
        streaming_pull_future.result()  # Block until the shutdown is complete.


@app.get("/")
def home(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return {
        "message": "Welcome!"
    }
```

Is there a way to listen pubsub messages continuously in FastAPI?

Thanks!

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publish-receive-messages-client-library
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/websockets/

Answer (score 1):

I've solved problem just by deleting:

```
with subscriber:
    try:
        streaming_pull_future.result(timeout=5)
    except TimeoutError:
        streaming_pull_future.cancel()  # Trigger the shutdown.
        streaming_pull_future.result()  # Block until the shutdown is complete.
```

Comment: do your endpoints even work?

Comment: @sgvolpe yeah everything works as expected. We've been using it over 1 year ^^

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same thing and the below snipper worked for me.

Start the subscrtipion from the startup event like

```
async def process_subscription():
    def callback(message: pubsub_v1.subscriber.message.Message) -> None:
        print(f"Received {message}.")
        message.ack()
    subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)
    print(f"Listening for messages on {subscription_path}..\n")

@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    # Start the background task to receive and process messages
    process_subscription()
```

Note: please import the necessary dependencies

Comment: Ok, but what would happen if you have a network issue for like 10 minutes or so?

Comment: by doing this the fastapi app doesn't work. You will not see swagger doc for instace.